# Microsoft Access - Joining Tables w/ different number of rows

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to make a Microsoft Access query of two tables that have similar columns, except one table has budget numbers and the other has what was actually spent
The two tables have a different number of rows, and since the only differences between the two tables is whether the information is about budget or what was actually spent, in the query (with an inner join) it duplicates the rows of the table with less rows because it still matches the table with more rows. I think an illustration would be easier to explain

BudgetTable:

```
BCol1 | BCol2 |    BCol3   |   BCol4  | Budget
Bill  |   M   | Employed   | Single   |  $45
Mary  |   F   | Employed   | Married  |  $48
Steve |   M   | Unemployed | Divorced |  $38
Grace |   F   | Employed   | Divorced |  $48
Frank |   M   | Employed   | Single   |  $50
Bill  |   M   | Employed   | Single   |  $10
Mary  |   F   | Employed   | Married  |   $8
Grace |   F   | Unemployed | Married  |  $20
```

ActualTable:

```
ACol1 | ACol2 |   ACol3    | ACol4    | Actual
Bill  |   M   | Employed   | Single   |  $28
Mary  |   F   | Employed   | Married  |  $32
Steve |   M   | Unemployed | Divorced |  $21
Frank |   M   | Employed   | Single   |  $33
Grace |   F   | Unemployed | Married  |  $13
Grace |   F   | Employed   | Divorced |  $29
```

When I make the joins, I join everything except the last column (since there's no one column that is an absolutely distinguishing feature)

But, since there are two entries for Bill and Mary in the Budget Table, in the query, it doubles the Bill and Mary rows in the Actual Table so it comes out to

```
BCol1 | BCol2 | BCol3      | BCol4    | Budget | ACol1 | ACol2 | ACol3      | ACol4    | Actual
Bill  | M     | Employed   | Single   | $45    | Bill  | M     | Employed   | Single   | $28
Mary  | F     | Employed   | Married  | $48    | Mary  | F     | Employed   | Married  | $32
Steve | M     | Unemployed | Divorced | $38    | Steve | M     | Unemployed | Divorced | $21
Grace | F     | Employed   | Divorced | $48    | Grace | F     | Employed   | Divorced | $29
Frank | M     | Employed   | Single   | $50    | Frank | M     | Employed   | Single   | $33
Bill  | M     | Employed   | Single   | $10    | Bill  | M     | Employed   | Single   | $28
Mary  | F     | Employed   | Married  | $8     | Mary  | F     | Employed   | Married  | $32
Grace | F     | Unemployed | Married  | $20    | Grace | F     | Unemployed | Married  | $13
```

And I'd want it to be:

```
BCol1 |  BCol2 | BCol3      | BCol4    | Budget | ACol1 | ACol2 | ACol3      | ACol4    | Actual
Bill  |  M     | Employed   | Single   | $45    | Bill  | M     | Employed   | Single   | $28
Mary  |  F     | Employed   | Married  | $48    | Mary  | F     | Employed   | Married  | $32
Steve |  M     | Unemployed | Divorced | $38    | Steve | M     | Unemployed | Divorced | $21
Grace |  F     | Employed   | Divorced | $48    | Grace | F     | Employed   | Divorced | $29
Frank |  M     | Employed   | Single   | $50    | Frank | M     | Employed   | Single   | $33
Bill  |  M     | Employed   | Single   | $10    | 
Mary  |  F     | Employed   | Married  | $8     | 
Grace |  F     | Unemployed | Married  | $20    | Grace | F     | Unemployed | Married  | $13
```

Is there a way to do this in Access?

Comment: Can you show the query that you are using to do your join? What column are you joining on? When you say you join everything are you specifying every column in your join or are you using a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Can you post your query in its current state?

Comment: It looks like the third table in my question, unfortunately I can't post my real query or tables

Comment: Without a way to differentiate "Bill, Budget = $45" from "Bill, Budget = $10" (for instance), you won't be able to specify how to perform the join differently. But you CAN combine the two entries for Bill (Budget = $55) and join that to his one Actual record.

Comment: I'm not able to manipulate the tables (I just don't have that level of access), is there a way to still combine the two entries for Bill?

Comment: Your tables do respect the basics of relational design. There is no point using a relation database if you don't design the tables following the basic rules of the relational model ! Google for database normalisation and review (deeply) your structure !

Comment: There is no need to manipulate the tables. First build a query that aggregates Budget numbers by person. Then create your final query joining the Budget Query and the Actual table.

Answer (score 0):

Why is "Bill-M-Employed-Single" in table A twice? Is the first Bill, with a $45 budget, a different Bill from the one with the $10 budget?

If, looking at your data, a human being can't tell the two Bills apart, then the Access query won't either.

What you will need to do is make it so that each Bill has a unique identifier. In fact, they could all do with unique identifiers. Each table should have an ID field and you could join on those ID fields, instead of joining on each individual field.

EDIT: Based on the comments, and the revelation that it IS the same Bill, but with two different budgets, then really you need to be linking between budget-actual pairs. Each Job, which has a budget and an actual, should have some form of identifier, really. If you were to ask Bill how much he spent on a Job, surely his response would be: "Which one?"

Comment: It's the same Bill, but say that he has two jobs and that's his budget associated with the second job

Sorry, my example could use some work

The issue is that the tables aren't in the same order, so adding an ID field wouldn't work

Comment: This is really messy. You want a link between budget-actual pairs then, and not use the Person to identify the link.

Comment: I also don't have access to be able to change the tables

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a query like this will work. Replace it with the names of your columns and tables though and the Employed Bill will show up as two rows since he is specified twice in the budget table, yet only once in the Actual table.

```
Select b.name, b.sex, b.employed, b.relationship, b.budget, 
a.name, a.sex, a.employed, a.relationship, a.actual
from budget b
inner join actual a
on (b.name = a.name and b.employed = a.employed)
```